# java program: decrypting side of a a rail fence cipher

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, char

I am struggling to get the loop to put a char in each required index, my error is at the `plainText.charAt(count)`. The error reads:

> cant convert from string to char

Any tips how I could fix this, Thanks.

```
char array[][]= new char [key][plainText.length()];
             for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                 for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {

                 }
             }
             int g = plainText.length();
             int count=0;
             int c=0;
             int a=0, b=0;
             int init =(2*key)-2;
             a = init -2;
             b = 2;
             for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                for (int col = row; col < array[row].length;) { // take out row++ want to stay on first row
                    if ( count != g){
                        if(row==0||row==key-1){
                            col+=init;
                            array[row][col]= " " + plainText.charAt(count); 
                        }else {
                            array[row][col]= "" + plainText.charAt(count);
                        }
                    }

                }enter code here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty string `" "`,and you have this:

```
array[row][col] = plainText.charAt(count);
```

And add col++ increment like:

```
  for (int col = row; col < array[row].length;col++) {
```

Comment: cool thanks, its giving out of bounds exception now, must look over it again

Comment: @b.d remove this  line: col+=init;

Comment: If i remove that, it will not put a character on the next colum

Comment: @b.d no problem remove col+=init; and add col++ in you for loop like above